# Vector bundle and disjoint union

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

My question is quite straightforward : given a $C^r$-manifold $X$ and a vector bundle $\pi : E \to X$ on $X$, is it true that $E \simeq \bigsqcup_{x \in} E_x$, where $E_x = \pi^{-1}(x)$? That is, can we always think of a vector bundle as the disjoint union of the fibers $E_x$, not just intuitively but also rigourously ? *A priori*, it seems there is not canonical diffeomorphism between the two.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **sets**, there is a bijection between the two, yes. When you ask for a "diffeomorphism," you first need to give a smoothness structure on the disjoint union of the fibers. If your smoothness structure is inherited from the structure on each fiber in the original vector bundle $E$, then there's generally no such diffeomorphism, for if $X$ is connected, then so is $E$, but the disjoint union will typically have infinitely many connected components (if $X$ is anything other than a single point). Hence the two sets are not even homoemorphic, let alone diffeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! How you would come up with a bijection though?

Comment: I guess $E \to \bigsqcup_x E_x$ defined by $v \mapsto (\pi(v), v)$ works, right?

Comment: Yes, something like that. (I don't know how you represent the disjoint union, which looks more like a cartesian product when you write $(\pi(v), v)$.)

Comment: As an exercise, you might want to look at the mobius strip, which is a 1-bundle over $S^1$, and compare it to an infinite disjoint union of lines.